# Alterar nome de usuário no Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Formatei meu ubuntu e digitei errado o nome.

Tentei consertar alterando os arquivos /etc/hostname e /etc/hosts mas ainda não consegui o que quero.

Quando abro o terminal aparece assim:

> **daneil**@daniel:~$

Preciso de:

> **daniel**@daniel:~$

O nome (antes do @) está errado, como consertar?

Comment: Não sei se isso está dentro do escopo definido pela comunidade.

Comment: @Patrick, acredito que não. Sistemas operacionais não são ferramentas primárias para programadores. Acho que seria muito genérico aceitar isso. E acabaria tornando esse site uma mistura entre o [su] e o [pt.so].

Comment: @Renan O fato de um comando como `usermod` poder ser usado num script não torna a pergunta sobre scripts.

Comment: @bfavaretto ok, concordo. Se alterarmos a pergunta para algo do tipo "como mudo o nome do (usuário/host)" com shellscript, a pergunta ficaria mais em tópico?

Comment: @Renan, eu acho que não, porque a resposta não muda muito, certo? É uma maneira artificial de "encaixar" a pergunta. Se você acha que devemos aceitar perguntas sobre uso de linha de comando no estilo [su], não quer abrir uma discussão no meta?

Comment: Feito ([de certa forma](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic/1880#1880)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente:

```
usermod -l nomeNovo nomeAntigo
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que precisa de estar logado como outro usuário (de preferência o root) e que também deve mudar a pasta do usuário para o novo nome.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou certinho, criei outro user admin para poder executar o comando, alterei e deletei o user novamente.
Obrigado. Boa noite.

Comment: Somente alterar o nome da pasta do usuário que não funcionou, quando alterei ele não entra no modo gráfico, aí tive que voltar no nome antigo da pasta, o que poderia ser?

Comment: Resolvido: 
mv /home/nomeAntigo /home/SeuNome
usermod --home /home/SeuNome NomeDoUsuário