# Como alterar a exibição do nome de usuário no terminal Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, terminal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso alterar a exibição do meu nome de usuário no terminal ?
Com esse texto muito grande, acaba atrapalhando.

Comment: Essa pergunta me parece fora do escopo, ja que está perguntando como alterar o nome de usuario do sistema operacional.

Comment: @Articuno acho que ele não quer mudar o nome do terminal, ele quer uma solução para diminuir o nome que está aparecendo antes do comando (isso também atrapalha, na minha opinião), mas creio que a pergunta não cabe ao site. Vou ver se tem algo no SOEN pra confirmar.

Comment: É só a exibição do nome mesmo

Comment: @RafaelÁquila a pergunta foge do escopo do nosso site, mas pode tentar essa [resposta](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title)

Comment: Resposta de outra pergunta fechada aqui mesmo no site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30435/28595

Comment: Se o problema é estético, basta mudar o prompt, não precisa mexer no nome. Veja a variável de ambiente `PS1`. Pode trocar as variáveis para simplesmente não mostrar o nome da estação/host. Veja as variáveis aqui: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Changing_bash_prompt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O que está longo nesse caso é o nome do sistema operacional. Edite o arquivo:

`/etc/hostname`

e altere com o nome que deseja. A alteração será efetuada no próximo logon.